# Is there anyway to reduce gas fee for uniswap v3 ExactOutputSingleParams?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, fees, uniswapv3

Question is simple. Is there anyway to reduce gas fee for ExactOutputSingleParams ?

```
function swapExactOutputSingle(uint256 amountOut, uint256 amountInMaximum) external returns (uint256 amountIn) {
  
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(DAI, msg.sender, address(this), amountInMaximum);
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), amountInMaximum);
        
        ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: DAI,
                tokenOut: WETH9,
                fee: poolFee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountOut: amountOut,
                amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        
        amountIn = swapRouter.exactOutputSingle(params);

       
        if (amountIn < amountInMaximum) {
            TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), 0);
            TransferHelper.safeTransfer(DAI, msg.sender, amountInMaximum - amountIn);
        }
    }
```